# How to change gitlab default readme clone protocol to ssh

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I've deployed a self-hosted GitLab instance using docker. When I create a new project with the git instance default readme, I see these lines in the generated readme:

```
cd existing_repo
git remote add origin https://gitlab.pouyancorp.local/root/hhhh.git
git branch -M main
git push -uf origin main
```

but in the Admin settings, I've used `Only SSH` and also the clone URL at the top right corner is correctly set to SSH default.
in the `gitlab.rb` file, after a long time searching, I add this line:
`gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_projects_features']['http_url_to_repo'] = 'ssh://git@gitlab.pouyancorp.local'` and then went into the container and ran `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`, meaning I don't restart the container itself. But nothing changed and still in the readme file I see the HTTP as the clone or push protocol.
Also, I've seen that in the `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/projects/readme_templates/default.md.tt` file there is a variable called `http_url_to_repo` but I don't know how to set it or change it to use ssh.

Comment: can you share the documentation where you got that setting from? and whether you restarted as well?